# Coordinates changed after rotation XAML-shape

Tags: c#, xaml, rotation, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have figures (Grids) which I move and rotate. They placed in parent-Grid (name: Field) So, for moving I use TranslateX, and for rotation that:

```
private void RightTap_Rotate(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = sender as Grid;
        var objTransform = (CompositeTransform)obj.RenderTransform;
        Point cursorPos = e.GetPosition(obj);

        objTransform.CenterX = cursorPos.X;
        objTransform.CenterY = cursorPos.Y;

        objTransform.Rotation += 90;     
    }
```

i.e. I rotate Figure around its center. But after rotate I cannot find correct relative position of figure and Field. I use that:

```
private void Object_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = sender as Grid;
        var objTransform = (CompositeTransform)obj.RenderTransform;

        var transform = Field.TransformToVisual(obj);
        Point relativePosition = transform.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));

        //then I use relativePosition.X/Y
    }
```

I want to get the coordinates of the upper-left corner of the shape relative to the upper-left corner of the field, but apparently after the rotation of something going wrong.

Help me, please.

Comment: It seems you are creating a Windows Store App and not a WPF app, correct?  If so, update your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you were transforming a point from the parent to the child object.  Instead, you want to transform from the child object to the parent.

```
var obj = sender as Grid;

var transform = obj.TransformToVisual(Field);
Point parentPoint = transform.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
```